# Changes to ItemsControl's ItemsSource not updated in UI when tab is changed in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a wpf application with several tabs in a `TabControl`, where one tab is a log.  The button on the first tab adds a line to the log in the second tab. When the button is pressed, it also displays a message box 
containing the length of the `ItemsSource` of the log.
Issue:

- Press the button - message box comes up showing 1 item in the log
- Switch to the log tab (shows one line)
- Switch to the button, press it.  The message box shows 2 items in the log.
- Switch to the log tab, only one item is displayed.

Full Code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <TabItem Header="Microcode Process" Name="MicrocodeProcessTab">
                <Button Content="Single Step" Margin="0,0,10,0" Click="SingleStep" Name="SingleStepButton"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Log">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsControl Name="LogList">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2 { 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            LogList.ItemsSource = list;
        }

        private void SingleStep(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            list.Add($"STEP");
            MessageBox.Show((LogList.ItemsSource as List<string>).Count.ToString());
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF technology does not magically update target whenever a change is made to the source. It keeps UI updated through some notification mechanisms such as `DependencyObject`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

The data type used for the collection (`List<>`) does not have a notification mechanism. So the UI gets updated only once upon its creation and never again, that's why you see the log item added only the first time you go to the second tab.

(not recommended) You can do this to manually reset the ItemsSource every time a change is made to it. It will however always re-create all UI elements in the visual tree of the ItemsControl.

```
private void SingleStep(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    list.Add("STEP");
    LogList.ItemsSource = null;
    LogList.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

(recommended) You can implement binding for your ItemsSource by using an `ObservableCollection` - which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` - as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<string> _list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> list { get { return _list; } }
```

Note that an `ObservableCollection` automatically notifies the target of any changes made **within** the collection.